# How to convert from and to UTM coordinates in Mathematica?

Tags: geodesy

How to use the UTM coordinate system (northing, easting) in Mathematica using the built-in functions (`GeoPositionENU`, `GeoGridPosition`, etc.). There are UTM Zones implemented in Mathematica, e.g.:

```
GeoProjectionData["UTMZone33"]
```

gives

```
{"TransverseMercator", {"Centering" -> {0, 15},   "CentralScaleFactor" -> 1, "GridOrigin" -> {0, 0},   "ReferenceModel" -> "WGS84"}}
```

From N45, E15 one should get Easting 500000 and Northing 4982950.4 (zone 33), but I can't reproduce it.

```
GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{45, 15, 0}, "WGS84"], "UTMZone33"]
```

gives

```
GeoGridPosition[{0., 4.98494*10^6, 0}, "UTMZone33"]
```

(Easting offset 500000 is understandable - default, but Northing is way off.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've wanted to know this for a while too. Right now, I just use the function included in this blog post to go from LatLon to UTM: http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/17/mapping-gps-data/

Comment: The output of `GeoProjectionData` is not correct for the [UTM system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Definitions): the value of `GridOrigin` is wrong (it should be `{500000,0}` and so is the value of `CentralScaleFactor` (it should be 0.9996).

Comment: @kale: the short version of the function would therefore be: `ll2utm[coord_] := 
 GeoGridPosition[
   GeoPosition[coord, "WGS84Original"], {"UTMZone33", 
    "CentralScaleFactor" -> 0.9996, 
    "GridOrigin" -> {500000, 0}}] [[1, {1, 2}]]` and then `ll2utm[{45, 15}] // Round` gives `{500000, 4982950}`.

Comment: @Boocko, Except, you would need to include the logic to figure out what zone you were in and build a string `"UTMZone"<>ToString@zone`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in comments by WReach, the correct answer is

```
GeoGridPosition[ 
  GeoPosition[{45, 15, 0}, "WGS84"], 
  {"UTMZone33", "CentralScaleFactor" -> 0.9996, "GridOrigin" -> {500000, 0}}
]
```

The problem lies with the scale factor: 0.9996 and the grid origin

If you are familiar with projection systems used in GIS systems, you can check out http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32633/

Details are [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32633/html/):

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32633"],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH]
```

More explanations of the UTM system can be found [here](http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/GTECH201/Lectures/Lec6concepts/Map%20coordinate%20systems/UTM%20and%20UPS.htm):
"The central meridian in each UTM zone has a scale factor of 0.9996"

Comment: I feel this falls a bit short as an answer. Could you elaborate somewhat?

Comment: I agree with your diagnosis, although the easting should also be 500000 as the OP observes.  You might want to mention that the desired result can be obtained using the expression `GeoGridPosition[
 GeoPosition[{45, 15, 0}, "WGS84"], {"UTMZone33", 
  "CentralScaleFactor" -> 0.9996, "GridOrigin" -> {500000, 0}}]`.

Comment: Thank you, this works. But to convert back, the simple `GeoPosition` on previous output should work, but I get errors. Looks like the `GeoPosition` is not happy with `{"UTMZone33",...}`.

Comment: works in this way: GeoProjectionData["UTMZone33"] gives {"TransverseMercator", {"Centering" -> {0, 15}, 
  "CentralScaleFactor" -> 1, "GridOrigin" -> {0, 0}, 
  "ReferenceModel" -> "WGS84"}}, then use this: GeoPosition@
 GeoGridPosition[
  GeoPosition[{45, 15, 0}, "WGS84"], {"TransverseMercator", 
   "Centering" -> {0, 15}, "CentralScaleFactor" -> 0.9996, 
   "GridOrigin" -> {500000, 0}, "ReferenceModel" -> "WGS84"}]

Comment: @Tuku that works flawlessly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The settings appear to have been "fixed" (at least for *Mathematica* version 12).

Using Los Angeles, CA as an example:

```
(* Convert from LatLong to UTM *)
(* You need to know what UTM Zone you want *)
lat = 34.052234;
long = -118.243685;
elev = 86.654;
utmZone = "UTMZone11";
utm = GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{lat, long, elev}], utmZone]
(* GeoGridPosition[{385215.34335191007`,3.7686452431931966`*^6,86.654`},"UTMZone11"] *)

(* Convert from UTM to LatLong *)
utmZone = "UTMZone11";
utmEasting = 385215.34335191007;
utmNorthing = 3768645.2431931966;
elev = 86.654;
GeoPosition[GeoGridPosition[{utmEasting, utmNorthing, elev}, utmZone]]
(* GeoPosition[{34.052234000000006`,-118.243685`,86.654`}] *)
```