# How to convert from UTM coordinates to LatLong?

Tags: geographics

I have a dataset containing UTM coordinates that I need to use in GeoGraphics. I need to convert them to LatLng form. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: This might help:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17448/9490

Comment: If none of the solutions in the linked thread apply to your situation, consider editing your question to say why.